# react native Module parse failed: Unexpected token in all node_modules files

Tags: react-native

i'm trying to run a react app builded with sdk v 27.0.0 in newer v 33.0.0, after upgrading all dependencies i get this parse error in a lot of dependencies, example:

ERROR in C:.../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/touchables/TouchableHighlight.js 10:22        Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:22)

full log below.

thanks in advance.

ERROR in C:/Users/kanra/git/cbb/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/touchables/TouchableHighlight.js 10:22        Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:22)                                                                           You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.                                                            |  */                                                                                                                   | export default class TouchableHighlight extends Component {                                                           >   static defaultProps = {                                                                                             |     ...GenericTouchable.defaultProps,                                                                                 |     activeOpacity: 0.85,                                                                                               @ C:/Users/kanra/git/cbb/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/touchables/index.js 6:0-69 6:0-69                    @ C:/Users/kanra/git/cbb/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/index.js                                             @ C:/Users/kanra/git/cbb/node_modules/expo/build/deprecated.web.js                                                      @ C:/Users/kanra/git/cbb/node_modules/expo/build/Expo.js                                                                @ C:/Users/kanra/git/cbb/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js                                                                  @ multi C:/Users/kanra/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js C:/Users/kanra/git/cbb/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js                                                                                                                                                                                              ERROR in C:/Users/kanra/git/cbb/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/touchables/TouchableOpacity.js 10:22          Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:22)                                                                           You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.                                                            |  */                                                                                                                   | export default class TouchableOpacity extends Component {                                                             >   static defaultProps = {                                                                                             |     ...GenericTouchable.defaultProps,                                                                                 |     activeOpacity: 0.2,                                                                                                @ C:/Users/kanra/git/cbb/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/touchables/index.js 5:0-65 5:0-65                    @ C:/Users/kanra/git/cbb/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/index.js                                             @ C:/Users/kanra/git/cbb/node_modules/expo/build/deprecated.web.js                                                      @ C:/Users/kanra/git/cbb/node_modules/expo/build/Expo.js                                                                @ C:/Users/kanra/git/cbb/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js                                                                  @ multi C:/Users/kanra/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js C:/Users/kanra/git/cbb/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js                                                                                                                                                                                              ERROR in C:/Users/kanra/git/cbb/node_modules/react-navigation-tabs/src/navigators/createBottomTabNavigator.js 11:7      Module parse failed: Unexpected token (11:7)                                                                            You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.                                                            |                                                                                                                       | import createTabNavigator, {                                                                                          >   type InjectedProps,                                                                                                 | } from '../utils/createTabNavigator';                                                                                 | import BottomTabBar, { type TabBarOptions } from '../views/BottomTabBar';                                              @ C:/Users/kanra/git/cbb/node_modules/react-navigation-tabs/src/index.js 9:11-59                                        @ C:/Users/kanra/git/cbb/node_modules/react-navigation/src/react-navigation.js                                          @ C:/Users/kanra/git/cbb/App.js                                                                                         @ C:/Users/kanra/git/cbb/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js                                                                  @ multi C:/Users/kanra/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js C:/Users/kanra/git/cbb/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js                                                                                                                                                                                              ERROR in C:/Users/kanra/git/cbb/node_modules/expo-linear-gradient/build/LinearGradient.js 12:16                         Module parse failed: Unexpected token (12:16)                                                                           You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.                                                            |             locations = locations.slice(0, colors.length);                                                            |         }                                                                                                             >         return ();                                                              |     }                                                                                                                 | }                                                                                                                      @ C:/Users/kanra/git/cbb/node_modules/expo-linear-gradient/build/index.js 1:0-61 1:0-61                                 @ C:/Users/kanra/git/cbb/node_modules/expo/build/deprecated.web.js                                                      @ C:/Users/kanra/git/cbb/node_modules/expo/build/Expo.js                                                                @ C:/Users/kanra/git/cbb/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js                                                                  @ multi C:/Users/kanra/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js C:/Users/kanra/git/cbb/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js                                                                                                                                                                                              ERROR in C:/Users/kanra/git/cbb/node_modules/react-navigation-drawer/dist/views/DrawerSidebar.js 12:20                  Module parse failed: Unexpected token (12:20)                                                                           You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.                                                            |                                                                                                                       | class DrawerSidebar extends React.PureComponent {                                                                     >   _getScreenOptions = routeKey => {                                                                                   |     const descriptor = this.props.descriptors[routeKey];                                                              |     invariant(descriptor.options, 'Cannot access screen descriptor options from drawer sidebar');                      @ C:/Users/kanra/git/cbb/node_modules/react-navigation-drawer/dist/index.js 28:11-43                                    @ C:/Users/kanra/git/cbb/node_modules/react-navigation/src/react-navigation.js                                          @ C:/Users/kanra/git/cbb/App.js                                                                                         @ C:/Users/kanra/git/cbb/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js                                                                  @ multi C:/Users/kanra/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js C:/Users/kanra/git/cbb/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js                                                                                                                                                                                              ERROR in C:/Users/kanra/git/cbb/node_modules/expo-payments-stripe/src/Stripe.js 12:20                                   Module parse failed: Unexpected token (12:20)                                                                           You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.                                                            |                                                                                                                       | class Stripe {                                                                                                        >   stripeInitialized = false;                                                                                          |                                                                                                                       |   setOptionsAsync = (options = {}) => {                                                                                @ C:/Users/kanra/git/cbb/node_modules/expo-payments-stripe/index.js 3:11-34                                             @ C:/Users/kanra/git/cbb/node_modules/expo/build/DangerZone.js                                                          @ C:/Users/kanra/git/cbb/node_modules/expo/build/Expo.js                                                                @ C:/Users/kanra/git/cbb/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js                                                                  @ multi C:/Users/kanra/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js C:/Users/kanra/git/cbb/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js                                                                                                                                                                                              ERROR in C:/Users/kanra/git/cbb/node_modules/react-navigation-tabs/src/utils/createTabNavigator.js 12:7                 Module parse failed: Unexpected token (12:7)                                                                            You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.                                                            | } from '@react-navigation/core';                                                                                      |                                                                                                                       > export type InjectedProps = {                                                                                         |   getLabelText: (props: { route: any }) => any,                                                                       |   getAccessibilityLabel: (props: { route: any }) => string,                                                            @ C:/Users/kanra/git/cbb/node_modules/react-navigation-tabs/src/index.js 29:11-48                                       @ C:/Users/kanra/git/cbb/node_modules/react-navigation/src/react-navigation.js                                          @ C:/Users/kanra/git/cbb/App.js                                                                                         @ C:/Users/kanra/git/cbb/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js                                                                  @ multi C:/Users/kanra/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js C:/Users/kanra/git/cbb/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js                                                                                                                                                                                              ERROR in C:/Users/kanra/git/cbb/node_modules/react-navigation-drawer/dist/navigators/createDrawerNavigator.js 13:41     Module parse failed: Unexpected token (13:41)                                                                           You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.                                                            | // and the view's props                                                                                               |                                                                                                                       > const defaultContentComponent = props =>                                     |                                                     |                                                                                              @ C:/Users/kanra/git/cbb/node_modules/react-navigation-drawer/dist/index.js 8:11-56                                     @ C:/Users/kanra/git/cbb/node_modules/react-navigation/src/react-navigation.js                                          @ C:/Users/kanra/git/cbb/App.js                                                                                         @ C:/Users/kanra/git/cbb/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js                                                                  @ multi C:/Users/kanra/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js C:/Users/kanra/git/cbb/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js                                                                                                                                                                                              ERROR in C:/Users/kanra/git/cbb/node_modules/expo-gl/build/GLView.web.js 157:16                                         Module parse failed: Unexpected token (157:16)                                                                          You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.                                                            |         const domProps = stripNonDOMProps(props);                                                                     |         const containerStyle = StyleSheet.flatten([{ flex: 1 }, style]);                                              >         return (                                           |                                                                                     |       );                                                                                                         @ C:/Users/kanra/git/cbb/node_modules/expo-gl/build/index.js 1:0-25 1:0-25                                              @ C:/Users/kanra/git/cbb/node_modules/expo/build/deprecated.web.js                                                      @ C:/Users/kanra/git/cbb/node_modules/expo/build/Expo.js                                                                @ C:/Users/kanra/git/cbb/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js                                                                  @ multi C:/Users/kanra/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js C:/Users/kanra/git/cbb/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js                                                                                                                                                                                              ERROR in C:/Users/kanra/git/cbb/node_modules/expo-av/build/Video.js 165:8                                               Module parse failed: Unexpected token (165:8)                                                                           You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.                                                            |         this._renderPoster = () => this.props.usePoster && this.state.showPoster ? (                                  |         // @ts-ignore: the react-native type declarations are overly restrictive                                      >         ) : null;           |         this.state = {                                                                                                |             showPoster: !!props.usePoster,                                                                             @ C:/Users/kanra/git/cbb/node_modules/expo-av/build/index.js 3:0-43 3:0-43                                              @ C:/Users/kanra/git/cbb/node_modules/expo/build/deprecated.web.js                                                      @ C:/Users/kanra/git/cbb/node_modules/expo/build/Expo.js                                                                @ C:/Users/kanra/git/cbb/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js                                                                  @ multi C:/Users/kanra/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js C:/Users/kanra/git/cbb/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js

Answer (score -1):

Seems like You have not setup gesture handler properly.
Follow the [Official link](https://kmagiera.github.io/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/getting-started.html) to set up the `react-native-gesture-handler`

Also check if you have imported `TouchableHighlight`

`import { AppRegistry, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableHighlight} from 'react-native';`

hope this helps.

You're good to go!!!

Comment: thank you for your response, i installed the missing package with
npm install --save react-native-gesture-handler
also i made sure to import TouchableHighlight but im still getting the same error, i think it might be an error outside of my code and maybe in the libraries or how i imported them since it reports syntax error on the library, i coded this using sdk 27, then i tried running it with sdk 33, there might be something there that im missing.